# Why can't change text of label in asp.net from javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

This is html code :

```
<table align='right' >
<tr>
  <td><asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td> 
  <td > <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark">
     </div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This is my function script:

```
<script>
        function onSignIn(googleUser) {
            var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
             document.getElementById('lblEmail').InnerHTML = profile.getEmail();         
           // alert(profile.getEmail());

        };
    </script>
```

`lblEmail` can't display value, Why?

i try use alert, it display email ok.

Comment: what does profile.getEmail?

Comment: return value of check login with google email.

Comment: where is runat="server" on Label ?

Comment: innerHTML needs a lowercase i

Comment: good, it is ok.

Comment: Alkis Giamalis: please add 1 answer. i will mark ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type innerHTML with a lowercase i:

```
<script>
       function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
         document.getElementById('lblEmail').innerHTML = profile.getEmail();         
       // alert(profile.getEmail());

    };
</script>
```

Comment: LOL that was a bummer :p

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 2:**

Make sure your label control is outside updatepanel. If it's inside updatepanel then place your js code inside below function **too**.

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

prm.add_endRequest(function() {
    // re-bind your jQuery or Javascript events here
});
```

**Edit 1:**

Use `document.getElementById('lblEmail').value` instead of `document.getElementById('lblEmail').InnerHTML`.
Try using below code:

```
<script>
        function onSignIn(googleUser) {
            var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
             document.getElementById('lblEmail').value = profile.getEmail();         
           // alert(profile.getEmail());

        };
    </script>
```

Comment: i had try it, but it still can't set.

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net might have changed id. Try

```
document.getElementById('<%= lblEmail.ClientID %>').InnerHTML = profile.getEmail();
```

Answer (score 0):

profile.getEmail() function return any string value ? 
if yes try:

var value= profile.getEmail();
$("#lblEmail").html(value);

Comment: Did you read the question?  `i try use alert, it display email ok.`

Comment: Change it to

 $('#<%= lblEmail %>')
 set the ClientIDMode property to Static instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the previous answers haven't helped, you might need to "find" it using jQuery inside the table. So like such:

```
var labelValue = $("table tr td").find("#lblEmail").val(); 
window.alert(labelValue);
```